# Multiple similar questions from the same user

Tags: discussion

After answering this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179157/python3-palindromes-for), I noticed the user posted the same question 3 times in a row today. Now I kinda wish I didn't answer at all, because it feels like cheating to me. You have the issue of multiple answers that are the same, etc...

The questions are:

1. [Python 3 palindrome checker](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179150/python3-palindrome-implementation)
2. [implement unit test cases for python palindrome](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179141/implement-unit-test-cases-for-python-palindrome)
3. [My third post about Python 3 palindromes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179157/python3-palindromes-for)

Thus:

- What can I do when something like this happens?
- More specifically, what can be done to prevent this kind of situation?
- Should I just flag and let a moderator handle it? What do I even flag it as?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [site policy](/help/someone-answers), follow-up questions are allowed, and even encouraged.  However, doing so without adequate signposts is, in my opinion, rude.

- The old question should have a comment indicating that a follow-up question exists, so that people don't waste time reviewing obsolete code.
- The new question should link back to the old question, and it should explain what has changed, and why you are seeking another review.

If a user is flooding Code Review with questions about the same or identical code, you can vote/flag to close them as duplicates, or downvote.

Comment: This didn't feel like a follow-up question to me, since the time in between posting was only an hour.

Comment: @Ludisposed I suspect that the third question was posted in an attempt to circumvent the closing of the second one as "Unclear". In any case, my advice is the same: downvote, or vote to close.